# How to retrieve <textarea> value with POST and save to a file?

Tags: php, html, post, textarea

On the page "index.php", I have the following html:

```
<form class="centerd" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea id="html" type="text" name="html-text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

On the page "upload.php", I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("/files/test.html", htmlspecialchars($_POST['html-text']));
?>
<h1>From the textbox:</h1>
<? echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['html-text']); ?>
```

I want the text from the textbox to show up after the `<h1>` tag, and I want `/files/test.html` to be created (`/files/` already exists), and the text from the textbox to be put into the `test.html` file.

What actually happens, is whatever is in the textbox shows up after the `<h1>` tag, but `/files/test.html` is never created.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `"/files/test.html"` is an absolute path. Have you tried `"files/test.html"`?

Comment: Have you checked your permissions for the folder? Go to your terminal and navigate to the folder (`cd /path/to/root/folder`). Then type `ls -la` and a list of characters like `-rwxrwxrwx` should appear next to each file/folder. You want to make sure that the `files` folder has at least three `w` characters in that list. You can read more about permissions and how to change them [here](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml)

Comment: This is on my website. I'm using an FTP server to edit the files.

I made a script where the user can upload a file and it copies the file to the website, and I never had to change any permissions.

But now when I try to create a file, it doesn't work.

Comment: For upload.php:

rw-rw-rw-

Answer (score 0):

*I'm sorry that I cannot comment on what Brannon said, I simply don't have reputation for it yet. But to the point:*

There are two possibilities:

1. As Brannon said -> your path seems to be wrong.
2. You don't have permission to write (create) files in your directory. This can, in my experience, be a common error for Mac users who haven't provided permission in their htdocs folder.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the php!

not: `<? echo ?>`
but: `<?php echo ?>`

Comment: This is an 8 year old question...